# How to change address fields like street number to address1 for place autocomplete address form - Google?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to change id="street_number" to id="address1" but when I do that it stops working as I have changed the field ID. So how I can change id to address1 and still make it functional? As google dont allow me to change id to address1 or any other name.

Sorry if it's still confusing.
I have copied the code from the following link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Now, in the above link they have provided html code like below:

```
<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
         You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if anyone knows how I can change the field Id provided above to something else and then address fields get populate by google the way it showing in the above link example.

custom ID field not allowed by Google following code as if I change the ID then it stops working by not populating that ID's textbox.

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to change id="street_number" to id="address1" but when I do that it stops working as I have changed the field ID. So how I can change id to address1 and still make it functional?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like in this question: [Google Maps API autocomplete 2nd address fields on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547312/google-maps-api-autocomplete-2nd-address-fields-on-same-page), or do you just have one form that has fixed ids?  Is it only the one field that needs to be changed, or all or most of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `street_number` to `address1` in both HTML and JS like this:

HTML:

```
<td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="address1"
      disabled="true"></input></td>
```

JS:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    address1: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

Because Google Maps API uses `street_number` as key, so you need to change the JS code a little bit too:

```
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
       document.getElementById(component).value = '';
       document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

   // Get each component of the address from the place details
   // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
   for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

      if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'street_number') {
        var addressType = 'address1';
      }

     if (componentForm[addressType]) {
         var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
         document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
     }
   }
}
```

As you can see above, I have added a condition after `var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];` to check if it's `street_number` then replace it with `address1`, so google knows which element to bind street number with.

```
if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'street_number') {
    var addressType = 'address1';
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/o7rx90dg/1/

Comment: Thanks @M A you are awesome