# Multiple input with Google Places API doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

My problem is with the Google Place API. I can't set 2 input with autocomplete. The first input I read from a payload from backend and second input it is in a bootstrap modal

I tried with other solutions in the web, many examples but nothing work. I read the documentation and doesn't apear nothing of multiple input with autocomplete

```
function googleAutocompleteSettings() {
  const optionsGoogleAutocomplete = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "cl"}
  };

  $('.google_autocomplete').each( function () {
    const input = this;
    const googleAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, optionsGoogleAutocomplete);
    googleAutocomplete.inputId = input.id;
    googleAutocomplete.parentDiv = $(input).parent()[0];
    console.log("googleAutocomplete", googleAutocomplete);
    googleAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInGoogleInput);
  })
}

function fillInGoogleInput() {
  const place = this.getPlace();
}
```

the initialize is:

```
googleAutocompleteSettings();
```

the html input is this:

```html
<!-- First input is generated from a payload that I recived from backend  -->
<label for="estate_location">¿En qué Comuna o Ciudad buscas una propiedad?</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control google_autocomplete" id="input_estate_location" name="estate_location">

<!-- the second input is pure html, but it's in a bootstrap modal -->
<label for="attention_place">¿Donde quieres que te atiendan?</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control google_autocomplete" id="attention_place" name="attention_place">
```

I do this, and both input make the request to API. but only the first input have the autocomplete box. The second input, like a said before, make the request, but the autocomplete box doesn't apear

this is the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2gxmcnsv/2/

I can't put the API_KEY of google places API because it is paid for other person.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in the question itself, preferably a StackOverflow code snippet).  in the code you posted the jQuery `.each` is never running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API autocomplete 2nd address fields on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547312/google-maps-api-autocomplete-2nd-address-fields-on-same-page)

Comment: I put an jsfiddle, but I can set a non-billing api key :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem it was only of CSS.

This solve my problem:

```css
.pac-container {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```