# Getting "Undefined" when using multiple Google Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have multiple forms that are using Google Autocomplete on the same page. A bit of context on how the page works: Users can basically add how many steps they want (to add a step, the form uses the Google Autocomplete), and inside each step they can add activities (to add an activity, the form uses also the Google Autocomplete).

I know that by assigning different ids to each form, then getting the element by Id to apply the autocomplete and get the data, would work, but the problem is that each time a user creates a step, it creates a step id, and then an activity form will be assigned to a specific step id, which makes it challenging as in the end I can end up having a lot of different ids.

That's why I was trying a different approach through class instead of id. So let's say I have those 2 forms. They have both the "search_term" class:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control search_term" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="text" class="form-control search_term" placeholder="Search...">
```

Then I have basically implemented a for loop so that the program can read all the items that have this class, and then for each item implement the autocomplete + get data about a specific place. The autocomplete works. But then I get "undefined" for the first item when trying to get the data.

```
<script>
  function activatePlacesSearch(){
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName('search_term');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i])
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
      var result = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(result)
      if (result != null) {
        const location = result['name']
        const name = result['name']
        const address = result['formatted_address']
        const phone_number = result['international_phone_number']
        const icon = result['icon']
        const types = result['types']
        const user_ratings_total = result['user_ratings_total']
        const rating = result['rating']
        const url = result['website']
        const latitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
        const longitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
        const photos = result['photos'][0].getUrl();
      };
    });
  };
};
</script>
```

I am a bit stuck on how to solve that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API autocomplete 2nd address fields on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547312/google-maps-api-autocomplete-2nd-address-fields-on-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but i´m pretty sure by overwriting variable `autocomplete` you destroy functionality, maybe try to use dynamic variable-names for each autocomplete:

```
window['autocomplete_'+i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i])
...
var result = window['autocomplete_'+i].getPlace();
...
```

Comment: I just tried, the autocomplete function still works, but I get this error when trying to get the data: "Cannot read property 'getPlace' of undefined". Do you have any idea why?